# could not execute command lessc in odoo 10 Windows

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to ask about odoo 10 installation on windows.

I have error like this "could not execute command 'lessc' "
I have seen in another post about this problem, but their post just discussing about mac and ubuntu server not in windows.

Anyone can help me about this for windows? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need NodeJS:

> Less CSS via nodejs
>           on Windows, install nodejs, reboot (to update the PATH) and install less:
>
> `C:\> npm install -g less`

From odoo website:  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/setup/install.html